# Azure App Services - login to test page

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to login to the App Services test page so I can open the help page but I can't seem to find the login credentials anywhere. Any idea how can I log in? I used Mobile Services before where I can find this pretty easily: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/musings_on_alm_and_software_development_processes/2014/10/23/azure-mobile-services-prompts-you-for-a-username-and-password/ but this article seems outdated for App Services.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is the default configuration Home page. There is the .UseDefaultConfiguration() method invoked in the Startup.MobileApp.cs. The part of that is the AddMobileAppHomeController() which depends on the corresponding Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Controllers.HomeController reference. You may want to remove that from the configuration and add the configuration and the view that you want to see (i am not sure that MobileAppHomeController page you see can be customized). [Reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/updates-to-the-mobile-apps-server-sdk/)

Comment: Actually I don't want to customize this page just want to simply login. When I run the service locally I can simply login - just need to click on the "try it out" link. But when I deploy the service to my azure site then it prompts for username and password.

Comment: Makes sense. Here, we should differentiate Mobile Services you are trying to use and giving the screenshot from Mobile Apps where you have a slightly different development model and the things you have from the very beginning that are working out of the box. As far as i see, there is no built log-in functionality into the HomeController built in the Mobile App project template.

Comment: And as Mobile Services will be deprecated, they should be out of equation.